# Проблема в выводе списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Есть проблема в выводе списка: нужно, чтобы выводилось просто `1 2 3`, а выводитcz `['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']`, причем, если изначально в `L` просто написать `[1, 2 ,3]`, то выведет некорректный ответ.

```
L = ["2\n", "1\n", "3\n"]

file1 = open('int.txt', 'w')
file1.writelines(L)
file1.close()

file1 = open('int.txt', 'r')
a = file1.readlines()

N = (len(a))


for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(N-i-1):
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]

print(a)
```

Comment: `a = [int(i) for i in file1.readlines()] a.sort() print(*a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учтите, что сейчас вы сортируете строки, а не числа. Если подать на вход вашему алгоритму такой список: `L = ["2\n", "11\n", "9\n"]`, то на выходе будет: `['11\n', '2\n', '9\n']`.

Правильно будет всё же работать с числами, а вот в файл записывать строки. И файлы открывать через `with`, чтобы не закрывать их вручную:

```
L = [2, 11, 9]

with open('int.txt', 'w') as file1:
    file1.writelines('\n'.join(map(str, L)))

with open('int.txt', 'r') as file1:
    a = list(map(int, map(str.strip, file1.readlines())))
    
N = (len(a))

for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(N-i-1):
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]

print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 3):

Два варианта:

1. Использовать распаковку:

```py
print(*a)
```

2. Использовать цикл:

```py
for n in a:
    print(n, end=' ')
```

---

Вы забыли закрыть файл после второго открытия.
Чтобы избежать этого, используйте контекстный менеджер `with`:

```py
with open('int.txt', 'w') as file1:
    file1.writelines(L)
with open('int.txt', 'r') as file1:
    a = file1.readlines()
```